# After webview page finished loading and i set it to visible, it appears as a whitescreen for one second

Tags: android, android-webview

Im loading my webview while i show a splashscreen. I set the splashcreen to visibility:gone when "onPageFinished" and set the webview to visible. When its finished loading the webview appears completely white and seems to have a horizontal scrollbar for half a second.

I tried to set webview to visible before splashscreen ends but it didnt change anything. Also i tried to change the backgroundcolor of the webview but its always white.

```
override fun onPageFinished(view: WebView, url: String) {
                  super.onPageFinished(view, url)
                 webview.visibility = View.VISIBLE

                splash_screen.visibility = View.GONE
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add some delay, because it happens with web views depend on how web pages are made. Sometimes JavaScript does loading after `onPageFinished()`. It should look something like this:

```
Handler().postDelayed({ splash_screen.visibility = View.GONE }, 1000L)
```